# What is the definition of "dry weight" and "dry cell weight"?

Tags: nomenclature, definitions

As I understand it, the *dry weight* of something is its weight minus the weight of its water content. Is this the definition? What about *dry cell weight*?

Comment: Why would dry cell weight be different?

Comment: dry weight is used in non-biological sense too.. thats the difference

Comment: @terdon so the definition I've written of dry weight is accurate?

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/13692/561

Comment: some techniques enable to measure the individual cell dry mass using microscopy. The company phasics seem to have developped this tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my Henderson's Dictionary of Biological Terms, *dry weight* is

> The weight or mass of organic matter or soil after removal of water by heating to constant weight.

So yes, your definition is correct and it is also applicable to cells. The dry weight of cells is the weight left when their water content has been removed by heating.

Comment: +1 thanks. What does "*heating to constant weight*" mean?

Comment: @becko heating until further heating does not result in a reduction in weight. Basically, until all the water has evaporated.