# On the definition of gDCW (gram dry cell weight)

Tags: nomenclature, definitions

I need some clarification on the concept of *gram dry cell weight*.

The unit acronym **gDCW** stands for *gram dry cell weight*. My interpretation is that 1 gDCW is equivalent to 1 gram of dry cells, but I am not sure. Is this accurate?

For example, the [dry cell weight](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/11138/561) of mouse cells is roughly 300 pico grams. Therefore, in this case, one gram of dry mouse cells contains $10^{12}/300$ mouse cells (1 picogram $=10^{-12}$ grams). And if one says that there are 0.6 mmol of alanine per gDCW of mouse cells, this means that the total alanine content of $10^{12}/300$ mouse cells is 0.6 mmol. Is this accurate?